# Prove that Diophantine equation $x^2=y^5+7$ doesn't have a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to form one congruence relation on this equation?
The starting congruence relation is
$x^2\equiv y^5+7 \pmod {11}$

This seems wrong (for $x=2,y=3$).
Could someone give a hint how to prove this?

Comment: $3^5\equiv1\pmod{11}$, so $2^2\not\equiv3^5+7\pmod{11}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you have already been given the hint to work modulo $11$. *Make a complete list* of the squares modulo $11$. To do this it is enough to square the numbers $0$ to $5$, for after that we can get nothing new.

Now look at $y^5$ modulo $11$. It can be $0$. By Fermat's Theorem, if $y$ is not divisible by $11$ then $y^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, so $y^5\equiv \pm 1\pmod{11}$. Thus the only possibilities for $y^5$ are $0,1,-1$ mod $11$.

Now check whether one of $0+7$, $1+7$, or $-1+7$ is among the squares modulo $11$.